# Activerecord limit returns NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i'm trying to get some results from table in a controller using the **limit** method.

I did that on the controller:

```
@articles = Article.limit(5)
```

And i got **NoMethodError exception** : undefined method `limit'

But when i did it that way it worked:

```
@articles = Article.all(:limit => 5)
```

Although i saw the first method on ror guides, why it didn't work for me?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using rails 3?  The limit method is only available in in Rails versions >= 3.0.

Comment: @tzvika: The [Rails 3 release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html) mention these [new query methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#query-interface), and links to a blog entry that [describes them in more detail](http://m.onkey.org/2010/1/22/active-record-query-interface).